# In Flutter: Is it possible to use a Future<bool> be used as a property in another widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a `Card()` widget which contains a `ListTile()` widget.

One of the `ListTile()` widget's properties is `enabled`. I would like to dynamically set the value of this `enabled` property by using the outcome of a `Future<bool>` which uses async and await. Is this possible?

**Here is the Card() widget with the ListTile() in it**

```
  Card myCard = Card(
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text('This is my list tile in a card'),
      enabled: needsToBeEnabled(1),
    ),
  );
```

**Here is my Future**

```
  Future<bool> cardNeedsToBeEnabled(int index) async {
    bool thisWidgetIsRequired = await getAsynchronousData(index);
    if (thisWidgetIsRequired == true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**Other attempts**
I have tried to use a Future Builder. This works well when I'm building a *widget*, but in this case I'm trying to set the widget's *property*; not build a widget itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that for two reason:

1. enable does not accept `Future<bool>` but `bool`
2. you need to update the state after result is received (you need a `StatefullWidget`)

There are 1 million way to do what you want to do and one of this is `FutureBuilder` but if you want to not rebuild all widget you can use this flow (your main widget need to be Statefull):

1. create a local variable that contains your bool value, something like `bool _enabled`
2. on `initState()` method override you can launch the call that get asynchronous data and using the `then()` extension method you can provide the new state to your widget when the call will be completed.
   Something like:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAsynchronousData(index).then((result) {
      if (result == true) {
        _enabled = true;
      } else {
        _enabled = false;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

3. assign the boolean var to the `ListTile` widget